# Permanently disable network interface in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, 22.04

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04, and want to disable the Wifi interface on my machine.  I can use

`ip link set wlx0007324d4d34 down`

to take it down from the CLI, but that doesn't survive a reboot.  How do I make this change permanent, using netplan or something similar?

Comment: You can make it over udev at least I would try it this way.

Comment: The interface name wlx indicates that it is WireLess eXternal; i.e. a USB wireless device. Why not simply unplug it?

Comment: No, it's not a USB wireless device.  Not sure why the naming is coming up like that, but it's an AtomicPI and there's nothing to unplug.

Comment: Let's blacklist the driver. It will appear in `lsmod` As the output will be lengthy, paste it here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Here's the lsmod output.  https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Sxs2MSGXhj/  I believe the Wifi device is an rt5572.

Comment: Can you add `lspci -nnk | grep -i net -A2` please? And `udevadm info /sys/class/net/wlx0007324d4d34 --attribute-walk`

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 22.04, the network configuration files are by default located at `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` instead of `/etc/network/interfaces`.

Open the `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file and in that, the interface you are interesting in disabling, under the 'set' keyword - you can add the 'down' keyword and set it to

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        interface:
            activation-mode: off
```

Save the file and then apply the changes using

```
sudo netplan apply
```

You can reboot to check if it still appears in the `ifconfig`.

Comment: Hmm.  This errors out with a few issues.  It "netplan try" doesn't recognize the keys "name" or "down".

Comment: Expanding on @m-liess edit. There is no `set: down: true` option in the netplan spec: https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/stable/netplan-yaml/#properties-for-all-device-types

Comment: Please clarify... What is the "*.yaml" file? Which file? What do you mean by opening an interface inside a file? Where is the set keyword? I don't even see set or down keywords in your example.

Answer (score 2):

Edit the **/etc/network/interfaces** file and add:

```
iface <interface_name> inet manual
```

After that, restart service using:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: This machine does not have network-manager installed.  I can install it, but that seems like overkill just to disable a device!

Comment: The /etc/network/interfaces mechanism has been deprecated since Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 0):

The driver for your device is *rt2800usb*. You may disable the device by unloading and blacklisting its driver:

```
sudo -i
modprobe -r rt2800usb
echo "blacklist rt2800usb" >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
exit
```

Reboot.

Comment: This seems to disable all network connections, not just the wireless.

Comment: Didn't r8169 load after reboot? `lsmod | grep r8169`